# Adding row in Pandas DataFrame keeping index order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` and I would like to add some inexisting rows to it. I have found the `.loc` method, but this adds the values at the end, and not in a sorted way. For example

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dfi = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(6).reshape(3,2),columns=['A','B'])

>>> dfi
    A B
0   0 1
1   2 3
2   4 5
[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

Adding a inexisting row through `.loc`:

```
dfi.loc[5,:] = 0
>>> dfi
    A B
0   0 1
1   2 3
2   4 5
5   0 0
[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

So far everything ok. But this is what happens when trying to add another row, with index smaller than the last one:

```
dfi.loc[3,:] = 0
>>> dfi
    A B
0   0 1
1   2 3
2   4 5
5   0 0
3   0 0
[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

I would like it to put the row with index `3` between the row `2` and the `5`. I could sort the `DataFrame` by index everytime, but that would take too long. Is there another way?

My actual problem is considering a `DataFrame` where the indexes are `datetime` objects. I didn't put the whole detail of that implementation here because that would confuse what my real problem is: adding rows in `DataFrame` such that the result has an ordered index.

Comment: Don't know of a way to do what you're asking. In general adding rows one by one to a dataframe is very low-performance. Could you build a temporary data structure piece-by piece, then make it a DataFrame, and then concatenate the two and sort it once?

Comment: why are you trying to assign with string? e.g. "3", rather than just 3. your index is a ``Int64Index``; this is a very odd thing to do.

Comment: @Jeff you are right. I copied an example from `Pandas` doc which actually used strings, and I thought it was the general rule. Editing now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your index is almost continuous, only missing a few values here and there. I think you may try the following,

```
In [15]:

df=pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((100,2)), columns=['A', 'B'])
df['A']=np.nan
df['B']=np.nan
In [16]:

df.iloc[[0,1,2]]=pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,2,4,], 'B': [1,3,5]})
df.iloc[5]=[0,0]
df.iloc[3]=0
print df.dropna()
   A  B
0  0  1
1  2  3
2  4  5
3  0  0
5  0  0

[5 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: It works! I had read about `.iloc` but didn't really understood how it worked, and prefered not to use it... my bad. Thanks!